# Adhoc push notification not sending notification for iphone

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification

I try to use Adhoc push notification service for my app, But its not working. When i tested with the development APNs certificate its working perfect. I Followed same steps for Adhoc APNs as development APNs.

1. I know that development and adhoc tokens are different for same device.
2. I used both `ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2196` , `ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195` but still no use. For development `ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195`.
3. I also updated provisional profile after enabling push notification service in developer account for Adhoc profile. When i open the Profile i can see these lines

   < key>aps-environment
           < string>production
           < key >get-task-allow
4. I also updated provisional profile in `XCode 5.1` and generated .IPA file using correct Adhoc Provisional Profile.
5. I used same server PHP code which is sending notification for development devices. Changing the token to adhoc device token.
6. Am using `https://www.testflightapp.com` for uploading adhoc app for testing for clients.

What am making mistake here.

Comment: Are you archiving (or running in `Release`) using the Ad Hoc profile you mentioned?

Comment: yes archiving with correct Release, with correct provisional profile.

Comment: In the build settings, you've pick the Ad Hoc profile too, yes?

Comment: yes Adhoc profile, which is generate from developer account after enabling push notification for production.

Comment: Did you create new .pem for adhoc push notifications? When you send push notifications over SSL to Apple you use pem certificate which is different for debug and for adhoc / release.

Comment: yes, i know that i have to create .PEM files from two .p12 files one .p12 file is public and another one is private .p12 file, Also one pem file for development and another .pem file for production with different .p12 files

Comment: Any other point am missing ?

Comment: Assuming the user did approve push notifications, you can try to check out what you are doing wrong with this guide: https://wiki.pushapps.mobi/display/PUSHAPPS/iOS+Getting+Started
just look at the couple of first pages, and make sure you got all the technical issues right...

Comment: Strange situation, i did the same things as described in the link. still no use. One thing i want to ask do i have to place my PHP code in server? because am testing push notification for development from Mac book itself.

Comment: Can you please update this with solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When Testing using `ad-hoc` you will need the following:

- Recreate your certificates/key using the distribution `APNs`
- Replace the url with `ssl://gateway.push.apple.com` not sandbox
- Make sure your server has port `2195` and `2196` open on your firewall

Comment: 1. I recreated the certificates/keys for distribution , 2. Am using ssl://gateway.push.apple.com for adhoc, 3. Am testing it in my local machine same as development.

Comment: but if no code change than  it must work on local machine as well, as he is getting pushnotification from local for development.. is it necessary to  put  code on server for adhoc build testing?

Comment: @hardikhadwani when I test ad hoc I use prodution profile , what do you use

Comment: for deveolopment development certi and profile, for adhoc distribution certi with adhoc profile